# Chrome extension updating value in page from popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that displays a popup window when you click on the extension icon and displays a form.  So far so good this part works as it is supposed to.

The idea is to make this form does some calculation and when I press a button it should update 2 text fields on a webpage based on the 2 input fields from my form that have been updated by the calculation (the calculation part works).

This is my popup.js

So far I can make it change the background color on the webpage, so on click, it is doing stuff on the page, so that's working.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('add').onclick = function() {
    var maxPercOpenPosOut = document.getElementById('maxPercOpenPosOut').value;
    var percBuyAmountOut = document.getElementById('percBuyAmountOut').value;

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
            code:"document.body.style.backgroundColor='red'"
        });
      window.close();
  };
});
```

But I obviously don't want to change the background color but I want to fill in 
`var maxPercOpenPosOut` and `percBuyAmountOut` into some number fields on the webpage this is the part I want to update the value of.

```
<input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" name="max_open_positions_per_coin" value="10" placeholder="20" required="">
```

I have tried with `document.querySelector("input[name='max_open_positions_per_coin']").value = maxPercOpenPosOut` but can't get it to work.

Comment: Some sites don't recognize direct modification of an input's value. In that case you need to .focus() the input first and then use document.execCommand with `insertText` command, see the examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try somthing like this:

Inside popup.js:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) 
{
    // message for content scripts
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {...});
}
```

Inside page js:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) 
{ 
    ...
});
```